# File I/O, SHA1 sum and compression

Tags: java, io, cryptography

The function `hash_blog` is inspired by ["how git stores its objects"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects). It is supposed to take a `String`, append a header to it, compute the SHA1 of it, then compress it and write it to a file. The first two characters of SHA1 is a directory name, and the rest of the characters are the file name.

Since I am learning the language, I am looking for general review. Is my code idiomatic Java code? Are there parts where I could make the code better?

```
package yas;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream;
// import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class Yas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            hash_blob("yasar arabaci");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    public static String hash_blob(String content) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        String hash_string; // hold sha1 hash
        String input = "blob " + content.length() + '\0' + content;

        // Step 1 is to compute sha1
        MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte[] result = mDigest.digest(input.getBytes());
        { // to create namespace for StringBuilder
            // This code block was borrowed from internet ;)
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            hash_string = sb.toString();
        }
        System.out.println("hash string is " + hash_string);
        // Step 3 is to write to a file

        File dest_file;
        {
            File yas_dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), ".yas");
            File object_dir = new File(yas_dir, "objects");
            File dest_dir = new File(object_dir, hash_string.substring(0, 2));
            dest_dir.mkdirs();
            dest_file = new File(dest_dir, hash_string.substring(2));
            System.out.println("dest file = " + dest_file);
        }
        try {
            if (!dest_file.exists()) {
                dest_file.createNewFile();
            }
            try (OutputStream out = new DeflaterOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_file))) {
                out.write(input.getBytes());
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
        return "Dummy Return";

    }
}
```

Comment: Beginning to learn the language or beginning to learn Object Oriented programming as well?

Comment: @bowmore I have used Python before, I know the basics of OOP, however I am not much of a fan of OOP :)

Comment: Then why adopting an OO language?

Comment: @bowmore Because I was curious what Java would be like since it is a quite popular language.

Answer (score 2):

**Problems** :

- methods mkdirs() and createNewFile() return booleans to indicate whether they are successful. You should check and handle if they return false.
- IOException gets ignored, you print the stacktrace but clients have no way of knowing the method failed.

**Style** :

- This is one procedural block in which different concerns ( finding and creating files, directories, computing hash, converting byte[] to a String, ... ) are handled. Despite an attempt to limit the of variables scope with a block statement, variable scope is unclear and often wider than strictly needed. There is but one cure : refactor : extract method.
- variable naming does not follow [Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).
- Don't return a dummy return value, declare the method to have `void` as return value, and you don't need to return a value.
- Comments : step 1, step 3 what happened to step 2?
- `printStackTrace()` statement ends with ;; only one is needed. (probably a typo)
- loop over the byte array can be a foreach loop :

like this :

```
for (byte aResult : computeSha1Hash(input)) {
    builder.append(Integer.toString((aResult & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
}
```

- coupling should be reduced. The hashing algorithm (sha1), output mechanism (files) and byte[] to String encoding are all hardwired.
- use of magic numbers; replace with explaining constants.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have refactored the code and added second version.